# Move application servers from one domain to another

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, migration

I have built a new domain and created a trust between the new domain and old domain. I have migrated the users and PCs but have yet to move the servers.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to perform this?  We have 2 application servers, an Exchange '10 server, and 1 DC. All servers are '08 R2  Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like what you are after is a domain migration.
this is not a simple task and you need to do some reading and careful planing of how to do it.
there is a lot of things that can and will go wrong.

also the most important thing is to test your plan so you know what will happen and problems you will run into.

a few pointers:
i don't think you can migrate the dc as is, what you need to do is to setup a new dc and then decommission the old one and then move the old dc as if it was a regular member server without any dc.
but note that you of course need a functioning domain until everything else is done.

i also am pretty sure there is additional complications with exchange mailboxes, most likely you need to setup a new server in the new domain and then move the mailboxes over.

how to handle application servers depends very much on what you have on them.
as a minimum you will need to go thru any dependencies on the old domain including services running as a domain account.

a quick search gave the following links

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/06/10/exchange-2010-cross-forest-migration-step-by-step-guide-part-i.aspx

so, do some reading, testing and make sure you have backups in case something goes wrong.